# Generate a dictionary with one key and a many values. and the values should be a list

Tags: python

```
def gen_stu():
    students_names=['venkatesh','kiran','ravi'] # assigning the names of students
    student_marks=[]
    student_names_marks={}
    for i in students_names:
        for m in range(1,3): # asking user for marks for respective students
            student_names_marks[i]=int(input(f'enter the marks of {i} for subject {m}: '))
            student_marks.append(student_names_marks[i])
            student_names_marks[i]=student_marks
    return student_names_marks
print(gen_stu())
```

with output below:

```
enter the marks of venkatesh for subject 1: 1
enter the marks of venkatesh for subject 2: 2
enter the marks of kiran for subject 1: 3
enter the marks of kiran for subject 2: 4
enter the marks of ravi for subject 1: 5
enter the marks of ravi for subject 2: 6
```

i'm getting output as:

```
{'venkatesh': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'kiran': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'ravi': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}
```

but i need output as :

```
{'venkatesh': [1, 2], 'kiran': [3, 4], 'ravi': [5, 6]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dict.setdefault`

**Ex:**

```
def gen_stu():
    students_names=['venkatesh','kiran','ravi'] # assigning the names of students
    student_names_marks={}
    for i in students_names:
        for m in range(1,3): # asking user for marks for respective students
            student_names_marks.setdefault(i, []).append(int(input(f'enter the marks of {i} for subject {m}: ')))
    return student_names_marks
print(gen_stu())
```

Answer (score 0):

Bring back indent of adding key to dictionary:

```
def gen_stu():
    students_names=['venkatesh','kiran','ravi'] # assigning the names of students
    student_marks=[]
    student_names_marks={}
    for i in students_names:
        for m in range(1,3): # asking user for marks for respective students
            student_names_marks[i]=int(input(f'enter the marks of {i} for subject {m}: '))
            student_marks.append(student_names_marks[i])
        student_names_marks[i]=student_marks  # <------
    return student_names_marks
print(gen_stu())
```